# How to use 'fixed' floatfield for istream/istringstream?

Tags: c++, input, io, inputstream

C++ has an I/O manipulator called 'fixed' to input/output floating-point numbers in fixed (non-scientific) form. It works fine for output, but I don't understand how to get input working properly.

Consider this example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double value;
    istringstream("1.4e1") >> fixed >> value;
    cout << value << endl;
}
```

In my opinion, it should work like this. Input stream has some string. When we apply `fixed` manipulator on it and try to read a double/float, it should stop on a first character which is not a digit or a dot (dot is not accepted second/third/more times). So, correct output would be `1.4` (we stop processing input when we encounter `'e'`).

Instead, this code outputs `14`. Why? How it works and what is the purpose of `fixed` for input streams? How can I read a double from input stream and stop at `'e'` (leave it in input stream)?

Comment: `std::fixed` has no purpose for input streams. None of the arithmetic formatting manipulators are meant to be used with input streams.

Comment: @0x499602D2 ok, thanks. What about solution? Is there any easy way (without writing parser) to read a double, leaving `e` in input stream?

Comment: There's apparently no easy way. I'm looking through the code for the extractor and there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent the parser from consuming `e` or `E`. You'll have to read it out into a string and parse yourself.

Comment: @0x499602D2, can you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use std::scientific
I tried like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double value;
    cin >> std::fixed>> std::scientific >> value;
    cout << std::scientific<<value << endl;
}
```

input: 1.4e1 
output: 1.400000e+01

Comment: Not exactly. I need to **read** a value as `1.4`, leaving `e` in input stream. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This question is somewhat misleading. `1.4e1 = 1.4 * 10¹ = 1.4 * 10 = 14`.

> [...] it should stop on a first character which is not a digit or a dot (dot
>   is not accepted second/third/more times).

Why would it? The `e1` in `1.4e1` is *part* of the number: without it the meaning is different. You have to read it, if you want to parse it properly.

> So, correct output would be 1.4 (we stop processing input when we
>   encounter 'e').

This would apply if you were reading an integral type which "stops" the parsing when a non-digit character ([0-9]) is met or other conditions trigger (such as overflow or underflow).

Comment: If my assumptions are correct about your question, we might try to discuss a solution.

Comment: No, I want to read only `1.4` part and stop. Let's suppose we don't have final `1` and `e` is just a suffix to indicate some unit. So, input is `1.4e`, or `1.4euro`. I don't need to read any character after digits into my number, it will go to another variable. But I also need to read a double, not integer. Looks like there is no simple way to do that.

Comment: I see, @JIghtuse. But `e` and `euro` are different! If you had `1.4 euro`, it would work. Since the exponent has to be next to the mantissa, a simple space between them would work, for example.

Comment: @Steephen It has nothing to do with UDLs.

Comment: yeah, I know that one space change everything. I was interested in reading double and char after that, so `e` in `euro` are the same in this case (i.e., I'm not interested in characters after the first one).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to read a value as `1.4`, leaving `e` in input stream. Is it possible?

There isn't a standard manipulator for this, I believe that there's a way to define a custom ones, but it would be too complex. I haven't found an answer on how to do that here on SO, I have only found [a question about output stream modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053753/writing-a-manipulator-for-a-custom-stream-class).

Let's move to at least some kind of solution. That would be parsing it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("1.4e1");
    double value;

    {
        std::string s;

        while(iss.peek() != 'e' && !std::isspace(iss.peek()))
            s.push_back(iss.get());

        std::istringstream(s) >> value;
    }

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```